# “Network is unreachable” from Android but works great from Python client

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio

I am trying to connect to a Python SSLSocket from an Android app. I can successfully connect from both my PC using a Python client and from my Android phone using a Java client as long as I am in the same network as the server.

If I use mobile internet, the Android app suddenly can not connect to the server anymore, giving the following error:

```
failed to connect to /2a02:foo:bar:11f7 (port 4321) from /:: (port 0):
connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

Here comes the strange part: If I connect my PC using USB with my phone and use USB-Tethering for internet access on my PC over the mobile connection, I can connect to the server! So on one hand the different network can not be a problem, because it works using Python frm both networks, but on the other hand it fails on the Android app depending on the network.

Here is my code:

```
private void openConnection() {
    try {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = createFactory();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("2a02:foo:bar:11f7", 4321);
        out = new PrintWriter(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslsocket.getInputStream()));
        out.write("password");
        out.flush();
        running = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public SSLSocketFactory createFactory() {
    InputStream caInput = null;
    try {
        caInput = context.getAssets().open("server.crt");
        Certificate ca = CertificateFactory
            .getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(caInput);

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);

    } finally {
        if (caInput != null) {
            try {
                caInput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs during `factory.createSocket("2a02:foo:bar:11f7", 4321);`.

Comment: "Network unreachable" is an IP problem (in fact IPv6 in your case) not an "SSL" one. Make sure that your server is indeed reachable over IPv6 from anywhere. Tools like "tcptraceroute" and "mtr" may help.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But how is it then possible that access is not possible using the mobile internet connection of my phone, but it works if I use my PC over the internet connection of the phone?

Comment: On your mobile internet, the client may not have an IPv6 address at all and hence no way to contact a server only over IPv6. You should instead make sure your server is dual stack (IPv4 and IPv6), use a name in the DNS that resolves to both IPs and use only that name in your `factory.createSocket`. If the client OS/network is properly configured it will then pick IPv4 or IPv6 depending on what he can do.

Comment: The server is only IPv6, because I have no global IPv6 address.
I just checked and it actually semms like I have no IPv6 address over the mobile internet. But how is it then possible, that my PC is able to connect over my phone with the server over IPv6 although my phone has no IPv6 address?